# Problema con salto de Linea en Boostrap 3.3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Desde hace varios días no logra encontrar porque no se visualiza correctamente una vista, hecha con Java Server Pages y Bootstrap 3.
He revisado el código y no logro darme cuenta que cuál es el error, las librerías Bootstrap las carga correctamente e igual jQuery.

El problema es que en pantallas grandes, se ve un salto de línea raro que separa el campo Sexo y se ve una línea por debajo de su etiqueta, haciendo que el formulario no se vea bien. Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código (para ver el error pulsar en "Pantalla completa"):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <title>ABM de Afiliados</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="masthead">
                <h3 class="text-muted">UOM</h3>          
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Crear Afiliado</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form action="afiliado" method="post">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Nº DNI</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" required="required" value="" placeholder="D.N.I.">
                            </div>
                        </div>       

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" required id="nombre" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="domicilio">Domicilio</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domicilio" required id="domicilio" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="localidad">Localidad</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidad" required id="localidad" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" required id="telefono" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="mail">Mail</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" required id="mail" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="cuil">CUIL</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cuil" required id="cuil" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="fecnac">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecnac" required id="fecnac" value="" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="sexo">Sexo</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <SELECT size=1 cols=2 NAME="sexo" id="sexo">
                                    <OPTION value=1 selected="Masculino"> Masculino</option>
                                    <OPTION value=2> Femenino</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Guardar</button> 
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Si alguien prueba guardar el código que adjunto como pagina HTML, puede ver a que me refiero. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola Fernando, no se ve ningún problema aparente en el código cuando se ejecuta. Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir más información: aclarar cuál es el problema concreto, quizás añadir imágenes de cómo se ve mal y cómo querrías que se viese, etc. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: Pude ver el problema, hay que entrar en modo "Página completa" para verlo. Voy a editar la pregunta para indicarlo, pero por favor, pásate por los enlaces que te indicaba arriba, te serán útiles en el futuro.

Comment: Hola Fernando, comprendo el problema y creo que sé cómo soluciuonarlo, pero necesito que me definas cómo deseas que se vea en los distintos breakpoints de bootstrap (xs, sm, md y lg). Tu problema consiste en hacer uso de la clase "col" sin la clase "row" o alguna clase que maneje la misma, como "form-horizontal". Cualquier col que no sea de ancho completo tiene un estilo "float" asignado. El no respetar las estructuras propuestas en https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms unido a este estilo es lo que causa tu error. Si me defines el comportamiento esperado lo puedo solucionar.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, voy a tratar de aplicar tus sugerencias para la proxima. Saludos!

Comment: Como lo dijo Roberto, el problema es mas de estructuración, al poner clases `col` sin un `row` hace que se comporte de esa manera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basando en el manual de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) creo que lo que te hace falta es separar tus clases **form-group** con un **row**

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <title>ABM de Afiliados</title>
      <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Jquery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="masthead">
            <h3 class="text-muted">UOM</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h3 class="panel-title">Crear Afiliado</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <form action="afiliado" method="post">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Nº DNI</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" required="required" value="" placeholder="D.N.I.">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" required id="nombre" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="domicilio">Domicilio</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domicilio" required id="domicilio" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="localidad">Localidad</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidad" required id="localidad" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="telefono">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" required id="telefono" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="mail">Mail</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" required id="mail" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="cuil">CUIL</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cuil" required id="cuil" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" for="fecnac">Fecha Nacimiento</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecnac" required id="fecnac" value="" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label" style="float:left" for="sexo">Sexo</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <SELECT size=1 cols=2 NAME="sexo" id="sexo">
                              <OPTION value=1 selected="Masculino"> Masculino</option>
                              <OPTION value=2> Femenino</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Guardar</button> 
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aunque así con esta estructura se vea mejor, no deja de estar mal estructurado, a la hora de inspeccionar el código las etiquetas `form-group` se ven mal, creo que se debería agregar en la clase `form-group` también la clase `col` sea `md lg` y estructurar mejor el label y el div que contiene el input sin las clases `sm`